# Remote pathnames must be relative to the Data directory when calling db.replicate from a scheduled agent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

First of all, I know what the error means.  That's not the question.  I'm trying to figure out a replication bug-a-boo and stumbled on an anomaly.  Here's the snippet of code:

```
[snip]
Set s=New NotesSession 
Set db=s.Currentdatabase
Set view=db.getview("Configuration")
Set ConfigDoc= view.Getfirstdocument
Set CAREDb=s.Getdatabase("Server1/Acme", configdoc.careLocation(0), False)
Call caredb.Replicate("Server2/Acme")
[snip]
```

This agent is run on schedule on Server1 (in a database other than the care database.)

There's a replica of the care database on both servers, both in the care subfolder under the Domino data directory on their respective servers.  Configdoc.careLocation(0) = "care\caredatabase.nsf" but when I look at the log on Server1, when the agent runs, I see:

> 01/03/2017 02:24:55 PM  Pulling
>   D:\IBM\Domino\data\care\caredatabase.nsf from Server2/Acme
>   care\caredatabase.nsf

I don't know if that's the cause of my replication error or not, but I figure any odd behavior is a good behavior to eliminate.  So, the question:
Where is my agent getting the full path to the database on the remote server and how can I convince it not to use it?

EDIT: The added code:

```
rc = caredb.Replicate("Server2/Acme")
If rc Then
    Print "Replication to " + caredb.Filepath + " successful."
Else
    Print "Replication to " + caredb.Filepath + " failed."
End If
```

The log:

> 01/06/2017 08:10:56 AM  Replicator updated 1 document(s) in
>   Server2/Acme Consumer\ComplaintWorksheet.nsf from
>   D:\IBM\Domino\data\care\caredatabase.nsf 
>   01/06/2017 08:10:56 AM Finished replication with server Server2/Acme
>
> 01/06/2017 08:10:56 AM AMgr: Agent ('Update Locked Documents' in 'care\MCDefer.nsf')
>   printing: Replication to care\Careworksheet.nsf successful.

Comment: 1) replicate method returns a flag: True (indicates that no error happened) or False. Could you please check what are the result is?
2) path looks fine (it is just full path), what does look wrong for you?
3) Try to run command in console on Server1 (see see output): Replicate Server1/Acme care\caredatabase.nsf

Comment: What is configdoc.careLocation(0)? It should be "care\caredatabase.nsf". Also, you might want to try changing "Server1/Acme" to just "", even though that *shouldn't* make a difference.

Comment: I agree with JSmart523. Your code is treating both Server1 and Server2 as "remote".  I'm not sure why you're getting the full path (unless that's what's actually entered in careLocation(0)) I believe that would work fine if you are opening it as a local database by omitting 'Server1/Acme' from the call.

Comment: configdoc.careLocation(0) is indeed a relative path.  I've added code to check the return code (and spit out what it thinks the database path is.)  "What looks wrong" is that it's a full path on a remote server.  If you go to the client and do a File->Application->Open, you don't say "D:\Ibm\Domino\data..."

Comment: Have you tried acquiring the database using "" instead of a server name?

Comment: Specifying "" instead of a server name would mean replicate on the local server, wouldn't it?  I don't want to replicate with the local server, I want to replicate with a server other than the one the agent is running on.

Comment: Question edited with the result.

Comment: Okay... given the result, I'm confused. Would you please edit your question to rephrase what the problem is? If the replications are successful, exactly what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The log should *not* say "D:\IBM\data\...." when replicating to a remote server.

Comment: And like the original question said, the problem isn't with *this* replication.  I'm having other problems with the database which may or may not be related to this question, specifically values from an older documents intermittently overwriting the values of a newer document.  So eliminating this anomaly will hopefully put me one step closer to finding the problem.

Comment: Oh!!!! In that case, you can eliminate this. This isn't a problem, it's working as designed. As far as Server1 is concerned, it's a local replica, and therefore it uses the full path instead of logging `Pulling Server2/Acme care\caredatabase.nsf from Server2/Acme care\caredatabase.nsf`

Comment: typo. I had meant: Pulling Server**1**/Acme...